# HTML5 tag benefits

Tags: html

I've this simple layout in HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="header">
    <div id="nav"></div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>

</body>
```

I've translated it in HTML5:

```
<body>

<header>
    <nav></nav>
</header>

<div id="wrapper">
    <section></section>
    <aside></aside>
</div>

<footer></footer>

</body>
```

Is it correct?

And what are the benefits of using the HTML5 tags (header, section, aside, footer) instead of old divs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are new HTML5 elements like <section> and <article> pointless?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822024/are-new-html5-elements-like-section-and-article-pointless)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all about semantics.

a `<div>` has no semantic meaning.
`<footer>` does.

You can read more about it here: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/semantics.html#new-elements

Comment: You should have to put some detail about the topic which is in above link because  it is not working now :-(

Answer (score 3):

The benefits is that it becomes more readable for machines and for other programmers.

The downside is that you need to use the HTML5shiv to make it work on IE8 and below.

Answer (score 0):

As a newer version more easy, shorter and easy recognizable