# HTML5: why should I use section or article instead of div

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are new HTML5 elements like <section> and <article> pointless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822024/are-new-html5-elements-like-section-and-article-pointless)

So, there are a lot of new elements in HTML5. For example section or article. But it's unclear why should I use these instead of div element?

Many blogs say about semantic meaning end so on, but why should I care about it? Does it affect performance or makes the page more frendly for search engines?

Comment: a good sum on the topic: impressivewebs.com/html5-section

Answer (score 2):

> Does it affect performance or makes the page more frendly for search engines?

As of yet, no. In fact it could have the opposite effect on SEO for some of the new techniques  (like having multiple h1 tags on the page, 1 for each section).  Of course, the thought is that html5 will be the new standard and soon should positively effect SEO. As far as performance, I wasn't able to find anything to support this.

The biggest advantage I see is readability (and therefore maintainability) by seeing tags that are appropriate for what they contain instead of Divs everywhere and have the 'id' attribute refer to the purpose.

Also, some of the new tags have a special purposes, like mentioned above with the section tag, for instance.