# Why use anything but div?

Tags: html, xhtml, web

In HTML/XHTML, why use anything other than div elements?

They are basic blocks that one can use to build entire pages. Sure, they don't add to the semantics of the page, but HTML isn't about semantics, it's about structure. And why should I be concerned about semantics?

Any thoughts?

**Edit:** So the statement "...HTML isn't about semantics, it's about structure." has caused some fuss; it is argued as being all about semantics, although div and span (perhaps the most common elements) break this rule. Perhaps then, a better question would be to ask: *should* HTML/XHTML be about semantics?

Comment: If HTML isn't about semantics, then why are they adding more semantic tags?

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are new HTML5 elements like <section> and <article> pointless?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822024/are-new-html5-elements-like-section-and-article-pointless)

Comment: *HTML isn't about semantics* -- HTML is *nothing but* semantics.

Comment: Well, bikeshed is coming! After all, HTML is all about semantics and div only helps on presenting the document. E.g. why bothering about pushing divs instead of using a table when ordered data has to be presented? Well, there's a reason, I guess. But that's me

Comment: This question is moot, as the premise is flawed. As @Juhana said, **HTML is all about semantics and context**.

Comment: @jackwanders Then why can't we add custom tags to our HTML documents? (Going by http://html5doctor.com/your-questions-13/, it goes back to the whole standards thing, but the way I see it is that there should be the standard set of tags, and then any custom tags will just be treated as `div`s by browsers. In essence, turn custom tags into syntactic sugar for classed divs, so `<apple></apple>` -> `<div class="apple"></div>`.)

Comment: @JAB in most modern browsers, you CAN create arbitrary HTML tags. Your document won't be valid, and the browser won't apply any default styling, but you can use CSS to style those tags just fine. In IE you need to use javascript to create an instance of each custom tag before CSS can be applied. It's how HTML5 shims get IE to recognize HTML5 tags. However, this isn't recommended because there is no standard context or semantics associated with a tag you create yourself.

Comment: So should HTML/XHTML be about semantics? (See edit in OP)

Comment: this isn't a programming-related question at all

Answer (score 5):

Two important reasons:

1. Search engines
2. Screen readers

Search engines rank pages based on their content and also the semantics of that content.  Adding the proper semantics to your content reinforces the intent of what the content is trying to communicate and that allows search engines to place higher value on that content.

Screen readers also rely on semantically-correct content.  See [this](http://www.accessibleculture.org/articles/2011/10/jaws-ie-and-headings-in-html5/) article for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Not all elements should be block level elements and the need to specify what kind of element a div is for every div on your page is ridiculous. It is also easier to read.

Comment: But you can change the "display" property of the div elements so that they may be block or inline.

Comment: Yes you can but why would you want to? Semantics matter in my opinion.

Comment: Well it would negate the need for all the other elements. I must argue that I have never had a problem understanding a website using merely divs, and this is especially true today when you have element highlighting whilst working in an IDE.

Answer (score 3):

Because:

1. It's better to read for search engines.
2. It's better to read for human beings.
3. It's better to read for screen readers.

Use semantic html or burn in the div-hell! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Plus how your page is structured says a lot about what is on your page. Search engines will place higher importance on h1 than it will h6. It does more that display your data, it describes your data as well. HTML5 will have even more elements, so you better buckle up.

Answer (score 1):

Various email clients support differing subsets of HTML that frequently ignore external stylesheets, floats and so forth. In many cases, you'll have to revert to tables.

Answer (score 1):

Just look at a simple example of what your suggesting:

```
<div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>this is a paragraph which contains some <div>stuff</div> that should not be in a div</div>
</div>
```

Now, is that easier for humans, browsers, search engines, etc.. to understand then the following?

```
<div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>this is a paragraph which contains some <span>stuff</span> that should not be in a div</p>
</div>
```

There are different elements for a reason. Outside of being block and inline for style, the tags add a lot of information to a page which is lost if its all replaced with div tags.

Comment: I hate to say it because of the stir this has caused, but I don't find one easier to read than the other. It's the way in which the code has been indented that has given me an idea of the structure, not the use of the h1 and p tags. If they were all in one line, then yes, the latter would be easier to read, but who would do that?

Comment: Easier to read means that it is obvious that Hello is a header in the second example, this does not come across easily in the first example. Also, this example is 4 lines, if you had a page like this it would be a nightmare. I imagine wrapping everything in a div is like going to the food store and everything is packaged in unmarked brown boxes, good luck finding what you need!

Comment: Nice analogy, but does anyone edit websites today without actually looking at it first? Also, in a real website you would likely have id and class attributes that suggest exactly what it is you are reading. I just think all of these new elements are unnecessary and try to help the search engine more than it tries to help the programmers.