# Is it bad practice to use a div instead of a list?

Tags: html, css

Currently my code looks like this:

```
<div class="carouselTypo">
            <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-target="#active1">A</p>
            <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-target="#active2">B</p>
            <p class="carouselTypo__p" data-target="#active3">C</p>
</div>
```

The same code could also be written like this:

```
  <ul class="carouselTypo">
            <li class="carouselTypo__p" data-target="#active1">A</li>
            <li class="carouselTypo__p" data-target="#active2">B</li>
            <li class="carouselTypo__p" data-target="#active3">C</li>
  </ul>
```

Now I'm wondering, which one is better or correct? Or does it not matter?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+html+use+divs+for+everything) of [Why use anything but `div`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11871487/4642212). Also related: [Are new HTML5 elements like `<section>` and `<article>` pointless?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3822024/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you remove the default css I don't think it does matter in this case.

but you should always prefer to use the element that represents your elements prototype,
because sometimes the browser has different behavior for different elements.

for example lets take the the `anchor` tag.

you can make it in tow ways:

1. create a button which opens the href
2. create an anchor tag with href

if you remove the default css the look the same but they don't,
because the browser has other way to deal with `anchor` tag, for example with anchor tag if you hover the anchor you will see in the bottom the `url` address:[image], or you will be able to shift-click which opens the link in a new tab.

```html
<button onclick="document.location.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';">
          hover / shift-click doesn't work
      </button>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com"> hover / shift-click works</a>
```

maybe you can make the shift-click yourself for example, but there are more different can't be done by you, for example accessibility service  / extensions will probably react different with other tags.

So if you are making a list of something I recommend you to use the `ul` Although I don't see any different in non style behavior. (but again, for example maybe there is an extension which collects lists data and it won't work on the `div` method.)

Answer (score 0):

The functional advantage is that **divs** mean little on their own, whereas **ul lis** explicitly mean "this is an **un/ordered** list of items."

The term "semantics" refers to the way that you use the inherent meaning of existing structures to create explicit meaning. HTML is comprised of tags that mean certain things by themselves. And there are established rules/guidelines/ways to use them so that your published HTML document conveys what you want it to mean.

If you list something in your document, then add an ordered list **(UL)** or an unordered list **(OL)**. On the other hand, the page division (DIV) element is used to create a specific & separate piece of content.

The **div** element "divides." When you look at a page, there are specific parts like a content body, the footer, a header, navigation, menus, forms, etc. And you can use div tags to create these divisions. Often, the page parts correspond with a visual layout, so using explicit page divisions **(DIVs)** to cut up your layout in CSS is a natural fit. This way the div tags become structural.

If you misuse or overuse the **div** tag, it can create unintended meaning & code bloat.

To confuse matters: Google uses h3 and div to "divide" their listed search results. ul > **li > h3 + div**

So when you turn off all styles **(Shift+Cmd/Crtl+S in Firefox w/ WebDeveloper toolbar),** the **divs** should go away, and stack naturally. Your naked HTML should still render a nice page with a clear hierarchy: top to bottom, most important content first, and lists with bullets & numbers for listed items. And it's a good idea to add a link near the top (for non-visual users) that allows you to skip down to main content, important forms, or the main headings (like a table of contents).

Finally, keep in mind that you are building a document. Without all the visual effects, it should still be a cogent document.

Answer (score -1):

It will affect your code readability. If you use ul and li, your code is more readable.

Comment: But isn't that then a preference? I personally don't have issues with it as long as the indentation is right.

Comment: But if someone takes over your project, they will have problem reading your code.