# Div and semantic tags usage

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML. Been learning over 2 months+ and I am still confused about the most "**practical**" way of coding though I know I should not overthink it.

Question - For the example below, do I still need a **div id="header"** since there is a **header class="header"**? Is it because of the div's flexibility for styling purpose if I happened to add/style anything to it next time? I did see the Freecodecamp project website example having a semantic tag like header tag nested in non-semantic div. So I follow suit.

As for CSS, I never style anything to the **div id="header"**. I asked this question because it feels the div is a little redundant and I assume, lesser tags and codes make cleaner and clearer coding?

```css
.logo {
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.logo img {
    max-width: 230px;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: baseline;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header Wrap-->
        <div id="header">
            <!-- Logo-->
        <header class="header">
            <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="../t/img/b.png" alt="logo" /></a></div>
            <!--Navigation-->
            <nav class="header-menu">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Semantic markup: Why <header> instead of <div id="header">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748487/semantic-markup-why-header-instead-of-div-id-header)

Comment: You would usually use classes because they are more flexible (reusable for multiple items). IDs are unique in a document.

Comment: `<header>` is html5 tag which acts as header of website... where as `id = header` uniquely identifies element for developer to use it in javascript or css, `class = header` will have same purpose but it can be applied on more than 1 elements. In your css, you are applying style to `header` html5 tag and not on `id` nor `class`. So in above code you can say `div` with `id = header` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

When using a div you can style it using a class. For a single header tag in the structure a class is not needed.