# HTML 5, Tags Header, Footer, Aside, Etc

Tags: html

Hello everyone,
                I have just started learning HTML 5 and i am bit confused about the tags like Section,Aside,Footer,Header etc. Browser does not seem to render it differently unless we provide some styling in css file.

So my question is what are the benefits of using these tags if we have to provide the styling manually? Why not use the div instead of these tags we are using the manual styling in both the cases?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use HTML5 tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305723/why-use-html5-tags)

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781077/html5-best-practices-section-header-aside-article-tags) .. It will give you the rough idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason is why such tags as section, article, header and many others were introduced in HTML5 is because of the semantics. Of course, you can use divs everywhere, visually it will not have any impact. 
What is more, everything will named appropriately and you will not be forced to use id or class

Answer (score 0):

Using these elements gives a semantic meaning to your HTML so that computer programs would better understand the content. you can have a look [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/use-html5-sectioning-elements) for more details.