# HTML 5: Using <header> tag or class="header"

Tags: html

With HTML 5 new semantic tags were introduced which includes header and footer.
But i am confused what should i use and why?
Use header tag directly or give class="header".Which one is better and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<header>` and those semantic tags.

Why? Because they are meaningful, easier to read.

For example, consider

```
<header id="article-header">
  ...
</header>
```

and

```
<div id="article-header" class="header">
  ...
</div>
```

As you can see the first is shorter, and easier to read.

According to [Inbound now](https://www.inboundnow.com/html5-semantic-elements-mean-seo/), semantic tags are better in terms of SEO too.

---

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305723/why-use-html5-tags) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822024/are-new-html5-elements-like-section-and-article-pointless) question have interesting answers

---

**Edit:**

I'm quoting this from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics):

> Some of the benefits from writing semantic markup are as follows:
>
> 1. Search engines will consider its contents as important keywords to influence the page's search rankings (see SEO)
> 2. Screen readers can use it as a signpost to help visually impaired users navigate a page
> 3. Finding blocks of meaningful code is significantly easier than searching though endless divs with or without semantic or namespaced classes
> 4. Suggests to the developer the type of data that will be populated
> 5. Semantic naming mirrors proper custom element/component naming

Additionally, I have read somewhere quite some time ago that semantic tags are for defining the outline of the document, `div`s are more suitable for visual sectioning like box styling (I'm unable to find the source right now).

Comment: yes i get that but many times i have been asked that why these tags were introduced when we can directly use class="header".I hope to give more explaination than just reducing the line of code.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use header tags. The  header element represents a container for an introductory content or a set of navigational links. header tag has a block scope as same scope as a normal div tag .

```
<html>
<body>

<article>
  <header>
    <h1>Most important heading here</h1>
    <h3>Less important heading here</h3>
    <p>Some additional information here.</p>
  </header>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor set amet....</p>
</article>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS Definition

Class contruction:

`.` means a class

```
.header{
...........
}
```

HTML

```
<div class=header>
..........
<div>
```

while the header tag

This is calling the `element` name itself like `body` or any

```
header{
.............
}
```

HTML

```
<header>
................
</header>
```